# Write Custom query in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to get the some data and also last leave date of the employee with their employee name 
so i wrote this query
how can i do this in laravel 5

```
SELECT employee.firstname,employee.lastname,employee.id,hr_leave.*,LAST(hr_leave.date) AS lastleaveday
FROM employee
INNER JOIN hr_leave
ON employee.id=hr_leave.hrid
WHERE hr_leave.oid=$id

employee
id  oid  firstname  lastname

id is primary key

hr_leave
id  oid  hrid  leave_from  leave_to  days  reason

id is primary key hrid is the foreign key
```

Comment: What is your table structure, relationships, PK,FK etc?

Answer (score 7):

```
For Select --> DB::select('your query here.....');
For Insert --> DB::insert('your query here.....');
For Update --> DB::update('your query here.....');
For Delete --> DB::delete('your query here.....');
For General -->  DB::statement( 'your query here....' );
```

[Read this Article](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database)

Comment: some explanation could be better. Only giving links are not very good.

Answer (score 5):

```
$empls= DB::table('employee')
            ->join('hr_leave', 'hr_leave.hrid', '=', 'employee.id')
            ->select('employee.*')
            ->where('hr_leave.oid', $id)
            ->get();
```

more info - https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example:

```
$users = \DB::select(“SELECT users.*,products.* FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `products` ON users.`id` = products.`user_id` 
          WHERE 1 ORDER BY users.`id` ASC”);
```