# How to write custom query in model Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I tried to write custom query in model as local scope:

```
public function scopeLastSync($query)
    {

        return DB::table('clients')
            ->select(DB::raw(
                "select COUNT(*) as total, (SELECT created_at FROM clients ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)"
            ))->get();
    }
```

But it does not work. How to use easy: DB::query("native SQL query")?
I tried:

```
return DB::raw("select COUNT(*) as total, (SELECT created_at AS date_modify FROM clients ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you are searching for this, 
[Write Custom query in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402228/write-custom-query-in-laravel-5)

```
For Select --> DB::select('your query here.....');
For Insert --> DB::insert('your query here.....');
For Update --> DB::update('your query here.....');
For Delete --> DB::delete('your query here.....');
For General -->  DB::statement( 'your query here....' );
```

You don't have to write `select` inside `select(DB::raw(...))`. Try:

```
return DB::table('clients')
            ->select(DB::raw(
                "COUNT(*) as total, (SELECT created_at FROM clients ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)"
            ))->get();
    }
```

But why to do you want to write query of your own if there is powerful Eloquent Model.